# how get client via aadhttpclientfactory?

Tags: permissions, spfx-webparts, aad

I have a webpart that should be authorized via aad to have access to an API that is embedded outside (api is not on azure), this api is registered in aad as an application, but at the moment I do not know how to make aadhttpclientfactory allow me  for background authorization, has anyone already practiced something like this?